# Best way to support large picklist in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I have got more than 100 values in the picklist ,What is the best way to manage large picklist values in salesforce.

Comment: Thats so open. Just as easy to answer as what's the best restaurant in new york?

Answer (score 0):

The specific limitations on picklist value set size are [well-documented](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.picklist_limitations.htm&type=5), and there's no way to get around them. You may be limited to 100 (or even 50) if you're working with a specific standard picklist. However, custom picklists can have up to 1,000 entries.